# Num1 not defined when i run my file? although it is defined?

Tags: python

Altough Num1 is defined it is displaying an error saying it is not :(
i have tried this with and without int() but still produces the same    error. 
Just for context this is a calculator.

```
def main():
    Num1 = int(input("Please type First Number:"))
    calc = input("x,+,-,/")
    Num2 = int(input("Please type Second Number:"))

    if(calc == "x"):
        multiply()
def multiply():
    Num1 * Num2
```

Comment: you might want to read python's [LEGB scope rules](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined locally in another function, you need to have a global variable and use

```
def multiply():
    global num1
```

But the true solution is, you should make multiply function take arguments, like so

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
```

and you should call it

```
print multiply(num1, num2)
```

Edit: Call it inside the main() function of course, without global variables.

Comment: Thank you, totally spaced about that aha!

Answer (score 2):

`Num1` and `Num2` are defined in the scope of `main`, not in `multiply`.  You would need to pass those in.

I should also point out that your `multiply` function doesn't return anything either

Answer (score 0):

`Num1` is defined, but in another **scope**. In your case it's a function `main()`. You should either pass this two variables as a parameters or make them global.

Related: [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/1030110)